# How to write CUSTOM metadata into JPEG with Python?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, exif

How to write CUSTOM metadata into JPEG with Python?

I tried

```
import piexif
exif_dict = {
                'uwi': myvalue1,
                'activity_type': myvalue2,
                'prediction': myvalue3,
                'url_current': myvalue4,
                'url_previous': mavalue5
            }
exif_bytes = piexif.dump(exif_dict)
with open(filename, "w") as fp:
    test_image.save(fp, "JPEG", exif=exif_bytes)
```

but see nothing in images with `XnView`. What am I doing wrong?

P.S. I don't need to write camera model, exposure and other stuff. I want to write my own custom metadata.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to modify EXIF data in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44636152/how-to-modify-exif-data-in-python)

Answer (score 10):

I can’t find a clear answer about custom tags ([these](https://perlmaven.com/adding-custom-tags-with-image-exiftool) [links](https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=7377.0) suggest you can with a third party tool), but looking at the [specifications](http://www.exif.org/Exif2-2.PDF) gives only the defined tags so I’m going to say no, you can’t make your own metadata tags, at least not directly.

---

So what you *can* do is write your own data to any of the [defined](https://www.exiv2.org/tags.html) tags. It’s best to use the [MakerNote](https://exiv2.org/makernote.html) tag for this - most camera makers [store](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exif#Technical_2) their own custom metadata there. Dump your custom flags into a byte string before stuffing it into the MakerNote tag:

```
from PIL import Image
import piexif
import pickle

tags = {'url_current'   : 'https://stackoverflow.com/q/52729428/1846249',
        'contains_fish' : False,
        3               : 0.14159265358979323, }

data = pickle.dumps(tags)
exif_ifd = {piexif.ExifIFD.MakerNote: data}

exif_dict = {"0th": {}, "Exif": exif_ifd, "1st": {},
             "thumbnail": None, "GPS": {}}

img = Image.new('RGB', (500, 500), 'green')
exif_dat = piexif.dump(exif_dict)
img.save('image.jpg',  exif=exif_dat)
```

Because it's your own format, you'll need to read it back out yourself:

```
img = Image.open('image.jpg')
raw = img.getexif()[piexif.ExifIFD.MakerNote]
tags = pickle.loads(raw)
```

exiftool will see the image has a MakerNote, but won't recognize it:

```
C:\> exiftool image.jpg -MakerNote
Warning: [minor] Unrecognized MakerNotes - image.jpg
```

You could also store it in the UserComment tag - storing is done in the same way.

```
C:\>exiftool image.jpg -UserComment
User Comment                    : Ç.ò^}ö(î.url_currentöî,https://stackoverflow.com/q/52729428/1846249öî.contains_fishöëK.G?┬.╡DB╤äu.
```

P.S. there's a [limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exif#Technical_2) of 64kB for metadata in jpeg images

Comment: I get a key error in img.getexif()[[piexif.ExifIFD.MakerNote]], the maker note is an int that does not exist in img.getexif if I transform it into a dictionary

Answer (score 7):

Check out [the docs](https://piexif.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#dump) on how to use piexif. What you are doing wrong for example is trying to write custom metadata and opening the file with open instead of opening with Image from the PIL module.

Cutting down the example from the docs, you could do something like this:

```
from PIL import Image
import piexif

zeroth_ifd = {
              piexif.ImageIFD.Make: u"Canon",
              piexif.ImageIFD.XResolution: (96, 1),
              piexif.ImageIFD.YResolution: (96, 1),
              piexif.ImageIFD.Software: u"piexif"
              }
exif_ifd = {
            piexif.ExifIFD.DateTimeOriginal: u"2099:09:29 10:10:10",
            piexif.ExifIFD.LensMake: u"LensMake",
            piexif.ExifIFD.Sharpness: 65535,
            piexif.ExifIFD.LensSpecification: ((1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1)),
            }
gps_ifd = {
           piexif.GPSIFD.GPSVersionID: (2, 0, 0, 0),
           piexif.GPSIFD.GPSAltitudeRef: 1,
           piexif.GPSIFD.GPSDateStamp: u"1999:99:99 99:99:99",
           }
first_ifd = {
             piexif.ImageIFD.Make: u"Canon",
             piexif.ImageIFD.XResolution: (40, 1),
             piexif.ImageIFD.YResolution: (40, 1),
             piexif.ImageIFD.Software: u"piexif"
             }

exif_dict = {"0th":zeroth_ifd, "Exif":exif_ifd, "GPS":gps_ifd, "1st":first_ifd, "thumbnail":thumbnail}
exif_bytes = piexif.dump(exif_dict)
im = Image.open("foo.jpg")
im.save("out.jpg", exif=exif_bytes)
```

You can check all the metadata fields that you can edit with piexif [here](https://github.com/hMatoba/Piexif/blob/master/piexif/_exif.py).

Comment: But is it possible to save custom metadata in JPEG? I don't want to save camera model etc, it is unneeded for me.

Comment: Also I am not opening existing image, I am creating my own one.

Comment: Original poster emphasized he wished to add *custom* attributes. The example given is helpful, but, it explicitly references only EXIF standard attributes.