# Edit Meta Data of Image Python

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, meta-tags, meta

I am taking a picture with opencv, and all of the image properties of the pictures it takes are not set. I need to set the camera make, model, and focal length. I am using python 2.7. I have looked at piexif, but that doesnt have the properties I need. Additionally I have looked at pyexiv2, however the pip install failed when I tried to install it for python 2.7. So how do I edit the meta data of an image in python?

Comment: Your "question" does not contain a question. Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: i thought the title was obvious. but theres an edit to clarify the question

Comment: If your question is "how do I edit the meta data of an image", I personally would vote to close this as a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52729428/ - however you claim that piexif does not support setting the fields you're looking for. But when I look into the [piexif code](https://github.com/hMatoba/Piexif/blob/master/piexif/_exif.py), it does seem those fields are supported (at least, I found Make, Model and FocalLength, but then again, I'm not very familiar with exif data, so I might be wrong, plus I cannot verify that piexif fully supports it, just by having it in the code).

Comment: And if your question is about a recommendation of a different lib, then the question would be off-topic. That's why I linked [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), because in my opinion, your question is still not specific enough to give a detailed answer.

Comment: As an aside, why are you using Python 2?

Comment: I am using Python2 in order to link with other scripts in my projects which are all built in Python2.7, and are too complex to port to python3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PyExifTool](https://smarnach.github.io/pyexiftool/) is a tiny Python wrapper library around [Exiftool](https://exiftool.org/), which you can also call directly with `subprocess.call`.

```
$ exiftool -Model='My camera' image.jpg
$ exiftool image.jpg
...
Camera Model Name               : My camera
```

The parameters that you need are `Make`, `Model`, and `FocalLength`. Full list of parameters are [here](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/EXIF.html).

Comment: can i install this through pip?

Comment: `pip install pyexiftool`