# Add/Read tags on images Python

Tags: python, computer-vision, python-imaging-library, synology

I have consolidated all of my family's photos to a local NAS (Synology) and have trained a food/nonfood classifier. I used that model to predict my images and am ready to start tagging them. I have the Synology/Photos app and Digikam and have found success with tags shared between those systems. How would I go about adding one or more tags to images using python?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44636152/how-to-modify-exif-data-in-python answer your question?

Comment: I don't think so. I am looking at adding a custom tag to an image; for example tagging the image with the label 'Food,' not editing existing GPS tags. I have read through the documentation using PIL and I think that might work but have not found documentation that shows tagging images while preserving existing tags and demonstrating interpribility with synology/digikam or equivalent.

Comment: Did you find a solution meanwhile? Looking also for such a solution